# paypal verify payment from mobile

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am hoping someone can help me with a very frustrating situation.

I am implementing the verify payment call from PayPal, documentation here...https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

In the documentation, PayPal says that the CURL to check the payment, should look like this:

```
curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: user_id" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: password" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: signature" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-91B933855X481767M" \
-d "payKey=AP-70M68096ML426802W&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US"
```

So, to make the call, I have set up the following curl headers:

```
$headerArray = array(
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID:'.$payPalUser_Id,
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:'.$payPalPassword,
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE:'.$payPalSig,
'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT:JSON',
'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT:JSON',
'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:'.$appHeader
);
```

This is the URL i am sending to:
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails?payKey={$payKey}&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US'

And here is the code for my CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerArray);
$adaptiveResponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

whenever I run the CURL I am being told that my API credentials are incorrect. So I am really confused. PayPal asks for the "user_id", "password", and "signature" which I believe I have. Only thing is when you go to the classic API signature page (as they suggest) there is only an API username (not a user_id), are they the same thing? If not, how does one find their user_id? I have tried substituting the username with the email address on the account but that has not worked either.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Where do I get the paypal user_id?

Comment: Did you var_dump $headerArray right before making the call? Does it look fine? You should be using the API username (uas X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID), password and signature from your PayPal account, correct.

Comment: Did you use the credentials from this link: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-signature